# Javascript image mousedown is firing 2 events

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Javascript to accomplish the following:

1. An image is displayed when the page loads.  The image is a picture of a body part without an identifying caption, so it is called, in the sample code below, "Wk1_2_Medial_Border_uncaptioned.jpg"
2. When you mouse over it, a second picture, which is identical and has a caption, appears.  In the code below, it is called "Wk1_2_Medial_Border_captioned.jpg".
3. When you click anywhere on the web page outside of the image, it reverts to the uncaptioned picture.
4. When you click inside the image, it loads the captioned picture.

On a computer, you obviously couldn't click outside of the image without mousing out of it, so steps 3 and 4 probably seem redundant.  The purpose of steps 3 and 4 is so that the page will work correctly on Iphones and Ipads.  It worked okay on computers and Android tablets when I didn't have the onmousedown event in the body tag or in the image tag.

It seems like tablets register a tap on the page as both a mousedown and a mouseover event.  It seems like what my code is doing is this:

1. `Uncaptioned` image loads.
2. User taps image.
3. The image's `onmousedown` event is triggering, bringing up the captioned image.
4. The body's `onmousedown` event is triggering almost instantly, bringing up the uncaptioned image.

I'm stumped.  I don't want that onmousedown event in the body to fire, or I want some way to have the image's onmousedown event undo it.  But I can't figure out how.

Here's my **code :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../ptwebsite.css" >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script>
            function toggleCaption(picture)
            {
                var pic = document.getElementById("bodyPartPic");
                pic.src = picture;                      
            }
        </script>
        <title>Name The Body Part</title>
    </head>
    <body onmousedown="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_uncaptioned.jpg')">
    <div class="maincontent">
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a href="../main.html">Return to Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodypart1002.php">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1 id="welcomebanner">Can You Name The Body Part?</h1>
        <h3>Roll your mouse over the image to see the name</h3>
        <img id="bodyPartPic" class="portraitImage" 
        src="images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_uncaptioned.jpg"
        onmouseover="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_captioned.jpg')"
        onmouseout="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_uncaptioned.jpg')"
        onmousedown="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_captioned.jpg')" 
                />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onmousedown` is fired once for `img` and once for `body`.

If you want to prevent further event triggering on parents, you need to return false from method.

```
onmousedown="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_captioned.jpg') return false;"
```

should work.

And you can of course remove `mousedown` handler from body as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working.  I altered the image tag to read  

    <img id="bodyPartPic" class="portraitImage" 
    src="images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_uncaptioned.jpg"
    onmouseover="toggleCaption('images/Wk     1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_captioned.jpg')"
    onmouseout="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_uncaptioned.jpg')" 
    onmousedown="toggleCaption('images/Wk 1_1_Spine_of_Scapula_captioned.jpg'); return false;" />


And the caption still vanishes if I click on the image.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by what is called event propagation. A good explanation of what happens can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

The article also talks about cancelling this effect.

Comment: I'd read that article before but had trouble making sense of it.  It seems like it involves handling events differently than I did.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` to the end of `toggleCaption` to cancel the event propagation